# Using a MEAN Stack

Tags: jquery, migration, mean-stack

I have been developing a web application mostly using JQuery on HTML5. Over time, the code seems to have gotten a bit complex (over 1300 lines of code) and completely on the front end. There are two main parts to the code:

1. Reading sensitive data (formatted in JSON)
2. Custom algorithms

The code also has a number of event listeners. I have been advised to develop a server-client architecture. I have been researching about the MEAN stack and understand some basics but I am not sure how to migrate the code to the MEAN stack. I have the following queries.

1. How to divide the code between Angular and Node?
2. I do not wish to use MongoDB or any other NoSQL but simply read JSONs, would the MEAN stack allow me to do that?
3. Can I still continue using JQuery with Node if I do not wish to use Angular?

Comment: This question is too broad for Stackoverflow. Please read the help information (linked from the top of every page) to see what sort of questions are allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can accomplish your goals using only Node and integrating packages from NPM as-needed.

You can re-implement your client-side code using Angular to better organize it by taking advantage of MV* patterns.

You are not required to use MongoDB with Node.  You can use Node's file system API to read and write JSON.

If you wish to keep using jQuery on the client-side instead of Angular, that's no problem either.  However, if you're not using MongoDB or Angular, you're not really using the MEAN stack.

Answer (score 0):

okay let me answer you one by one.

1)**How to divide the code between Angular and Node?**

> Node is responsible for handling Backend logic and angular for front end.So what i can suggest you is that put all your custom algorithm at the node side.and reading the sensitive data if it is from user then put it at angular side and pass to the algorithm Using POST APi.

2)**I do not wish to use MongoDB or any other NoSQL but simply read JSONs, would the MEAN stack allow me to do that?**

> By reading JSON what you mean reading from file or something else.Yes you can if it is from file or user Input or some other API or source

**(check Documentation For:fs and lodash(to perform various operation on your data))**

3)**Can I still continue using JQuery with Node if I do not wish to use Angular?**

> Yes,you can.